# SerializationException: Could not find class specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

i am using schema registry with kafka for avro deserializer. i have made a postgres connector using curl request-

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' debezium:8083/connectors --data '{"name": "gps-connector", "config": {"connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector", "plugin.name": "pgoutput","database.hostname": "postgres", "database.port": "5432", "database.user": "postgres", "database.password": "password", "database.dbname" : "shipment_alert_subscriptions", "database.server.name": "postgres", "table.include.list": "public.truck_histories" }}'
```

and when the schema is generated the schema name is not what I wanted. how can i change schema name and its namespace as it is giving me some deserialization error as below-

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class postgres.public.truck_histories.Envelope specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.
```

Comment: Did you try this? https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/setschemametadata.html